# nvcc (cuda8, gcc 5.3) no longer compiles with -O1 on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: linux, glibc, nvcc, ubuntu-22.04, gcc5

I have a `CUDA-8` program which compiled (`nvcc`) well 7 months ago on Ubuntu 22.04, following [this procedure](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1442001/cuda-8-and-gcc-5-on-ubuntu-22-04-for-tesla-c2070), the underlying compiler being `gcc (Ubuntu 5.3.1-14ubuntu2) 5.3.1 20160413`.

After (not sure when) I upgraded some packages on Ubuntu 22, the program now only compiles if the optimization flag is set to `-O0`.

The minimal reproducer with file `test.cpp`:

```
int
main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    return 1;
}
```

And then run:

```
/opt/cuda-8.0/bin/nvcc -w --use_fast_math -Wno-deprecated-gpu-targets -O0 -x cu -c test.cpp
```

Compiles fine!

```
/opt/cuda-8.0/bin/nvcc -w --use_fast_math -Wno-deprecated-gpu-targets -O1 -x cu -c test.cpp
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string_fortified.h(104): error: identifier "__builtin___stpncpy_chk" is undefined
```

7 months ago, both variants worked fine.

I wanted to ask if there is something that can be done to fix this issue by amending the file `string_fortified.h`.

Comment: A temporary workaround is changing -O3 to -O0 in the CMakeLists:
`if (${CMAKE_CUDA_COMPILER_VERSION} VERSION_LESS_EQUAL 9.0.0)
            string(REGEX REPLACE "([\\/\\-]O)3" "\\10" CMAKE_CUDA_FLAGS_RELEASE "${CMAKE_CUDA_FLAGS_RELEASE}")
         endif()`

Comment: https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=29452

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the hint in this [bug report comment](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=29452#c6) (thanks Siddesh!), I came up with the following modification of the string_fortified.h header that solves the problem (you need to re-edit by hand every time this header is updated by your package manager):

```
# if (__GNUC_PREREQ (4, 7) && (!defined(CUDART_VERSION) || CUDART_VERSION>8000)) || __glibc_clang_prereq (2, 6)
__fortify_function char *
__NTH (stpncpy (char *__dest, const char *__src, size_t __n))
{
  return __builtin___stpncpy_chk (__dest, __src, __n,
                                  __glibc_objsize (__dest));
}
# else
extern char *__stpncpy_chk (char *__dest, const char *__src, size_t __n,
                            size_t __destlen) __THROW
  __fortified_attr_access (__write_only__, 1, 3)
  __attr_access ((__read_only__, 2));
extern char *__REDIRECT_NTH (__stpncpy_alias, (char *__dest, const char *__src,
                                               size_t __n), stpncpy);
```

Comment: https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=30621